# An Issue with watin in IE6 and IE7 browsers

Tags: c#, watin

I automated a web mail application using watin. Usually that web mail application, log off every 15 minutes. So to avoid this, in my code i refresh the browser every 15 minutes so that it never allows the mail to log off. This code works fine with IE8 browser. But I faced 1 problem when I try this code with IE6 and IE7 browsers. After installing this automated application, whenever I try to upload a file using this mail a modal dialog window comes in which we have to select the file(to upload). In that modal dialog window, when I click on browse button it shows ‘Choose file to upload’ dialog and suddenly it closes itself within a second. I don’t know which 1 is blocking this dialog to open. This is the method being used to refresh the browser every 15 minutes:

```
            while (true)
            {
                ie.Refresh();
                Thread.Sleep(899999);
            }
```

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a web mail application, I assume there's a web page involved?

If so, I would suggest taking that refresh loop out and using the [meta refresh tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) in the head of that HTML page instead:
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900">`

That might help.
At the very least, it should tell you if your c# refresh loop is the issue.